# How to copy an installer from the host OS to the guest OS in Virtual Box?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox

I have a setup file of a game on my Windows 7 host; to play it I need to run it in Windows XP - the guest OS, running in seamless mode - but I'm unable to copy it. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Virtual Box, the quickest solution is to set up `Shared Folders`. You can do this in the guest Windows XP Installation after the support tools are installed.

Simply go to the Virtual Machine options and set up a shared drive to `Z:` (or anything unused) and map it to the folder holding the setup program.

Then, in the guest simply go to the shared drive and either run the program or copy it to a folder on your machine then run.

edit--

After the tools are installed, you may just be able to drag and drop from the host to the guest - I know 100% that shared folders will work, however, I haven't used VirtualBox for a few years and not sure this has been added, I just know they were talking about it.